# MS Test equivalent to Nunits Substitue.For

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, mstest

I have seen the following code in a Nunit unit test

```
        var controllerDescriptor = Substitute.For<HttpControllerDescriptor>();
```

What is the equivalent code using MS Test?

Comment: those are two different things. The code snippet is for a mocking framework, MS Test is a test runner? The shown code runs the same for Nunit or MS Test. This looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: `Substitute.For` is provided by the NSubstitute library, not by NUnit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code snippet is for NSubstitute mocking framework and has nothing to do with NUnit unit testing framework.

MS Test is also a testing framework and the shown code runs the same for Nunit or MS Test.

```
[TestClass]
public class MytestClass {
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTest() {
        var controllerDescriptor = Substitute.For<HttpControllerDescriptor>();

        //...
    }    
}
```